# Is there an object or something that will always return true when compared against a time object?

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a ruby object that always will return true when compared against a an arbitrary time represented by the time object. 
In ruby is there an object or something that will always return true when compared against a time object?

Comment: You want to detect class of object?

Comment: no i want to compare a time object against something else and have it always return true

Comment: I think you should elaborate on *why* you want this, it will lead to better answers. Anyway, I do not think there is such a thing out-of-the-box, but of course you may implement a corresponding object which redefines the equal method you like.

Comment: lambdas are objects that respond a lot like methods. you're looking for lambdas I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a swing at it:

```
is_time = lambda {|x| x.class == Time ? true : false }
```

Comment: the question mark at the end of the variable is just syntactic sugar coating, it doesn't really do anything special for the compiler

Comment: Actually a question mark is not allowed in the name of a local variable, it is a syntax error. Moreover `x.is_a?(Time) ? true : false` is equivalent to just `x.is_a?(Time)`.

Comment: point taken    ......

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if this helps

```
require 'time'
a = Time.now

false == a.nil? #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use `Time` class to compare with the time object, using `===` method. Any time objects, will give `true` always, whenever you will be using `Time#===`. Remember in Ruby `Time` is a class, and again it is also a object.

Example :

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Time === Time.now
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: I am sorry I am looking for an arbitrary time compared against something that will return true always

Comment: @eat_a_lemon What is that *something* ?

Comment: Why not the something is `Time` class itself. As it always gives `true`, when you will be comparing it with any arbitrary *time* objects.